# Ajax 'complete' fires when Dom is ready or when everything is downloaded?

Tags: ajax, jquery, request

[jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says

> A function to be called when the request finishes

Does this mean it is called when the new Dom content is loaded (divs,etc) or when everything including images are completely downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

If fires exactly when request finished. If you getting some data, it fires when data received, and if you want place it into the HTML page, you should do that exactly in COMPLETE section.

Here is example:

```
function approveArt(id,val) {
$.ajax({  
    url: "/engine/approveart.php",  
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        'id': id,
        'val': val,
    },
    cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
                $("#curArt-popup").html(html).fadeIn(); 

    }  
});  
};
```

I send post request to PHP file, and when it done, I get some data from it. And when I get it (Success:) I place this data into the pop-up. So, I create new element when Ajax query fires successfully.

Comment: So you mean it fires "when the new Dom content is loaded",right?